# Is there a way to manipulate a 3D array with a 1D using vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying create a 3D array with ones in the first n places of the 1 axis, where n comes from an array with a length of the 0 axis. I am working with a large dataset and trying to speed this up.

I think the code will make more sense.  I am trying to vectorize the for loop.

```
    import numpy as np 

    data = np.zeros((3, 4, 5))
    num = np.array([2, 4, 3])

    for i in range(len(num)):
        data[:, 0][i, 0:num[i]] = 1

    print(data)
```

This is the result I am looking for:

```
[[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Comment: Is your axis=2 dimension large in real? and does order of 2D arrays in axis=0 matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but works:

```py
>>> data = np.zeros((3, 4, 5))
>>> num = np.array([2, 4, 3])
>>> max_idx = min(data.shape[2], np.max(num))
>>> data[:,0,:max_idx] = np.arange(max_idx) < num[:,np.newaxis]
>>> data
array([[[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

It's based on the following idea:

```
>>> np.arange(5)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> (np.arange(5) < 2).astype(np.float64)
array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
```

except with `2` replaced by a vertically broadcasted `num` to generate the 'first N elements set to 1, rest 0'.

Comment: This is perfect. I went without the optimization step so my code ended up looking like this:    
data[:,0,:] = np.arange(data.shape[2]) < num[:,np.newaxis]

Thank you very much

Comment: @RobLasch I added the optimization step because `max_idx` might be much smaller than `data.shape[2]`, but if it isn't then that's just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In code below I've presented three ways to achieve the required outcome with their runtime comparisons:

1. Your `for` loop.
2. `NumPy`'s `apply_along_axis` function
3. `Numba`'s `@jit` decorator, which basically compiles your for loop.

```
import numpy as np 
from numba import jit

def set_ones(arr_tup):
    arr_tup[0][0][:arr_tup[1]] = 1

@jit
def compiled_func(data, num):
    for i in range(len(num)): 
        data[:, 0][i, 0:num[i]] = 1

data = np.zeros((300, 4, 5))
num = np.random.randint(2, 5, 300)

data_num = np.array(list(zip(data, num)))

print(f'\n> for loop:')
%timeit for i in range(len(num)): data[:, 0][i, 0:num[i]] = 1

print(f'\n> apply_along_axis Loop:')
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(set_ones, 1, data_num)

print(f'\n> Compiled Loop:')
%timeit compiled_func(data, num)

data, num = zip(*data_num)
```

**Time Comparison**

```
> for loop:
288 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

> apply_along_axis Loop:
1.15 ms ± 43.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

> Compiled Loop:
5.45 µs ± 483 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

From the above comparison we see:

1. As @sai rightfully pointed out, `NumPy`'s `apply_along_axis` function **does not** perform better than the regular loop, and my take on that is that due to the relatively small number of operations performed in each iteration, the speed gain achieved by using this function is dominated by the cost of its' header, so not only there is NO gain, but it actually slower than the regular loop.
2. The third way, i.e. the `@jit` performes the best, and it is because the `for` loop is compiled. So basically, now instead of `python`'s interpreter, the `just-in-time` (or `jit`) compiler deals with this code now, which results in a `c` - like loop performance. More on `Numba` you could find [here](https://numba.pydata.org/)

Cheers.

Comment: not really, from my experience apply_along_axis is internally just a for loop

Comment: @sai - also don't forget that any operation is basically a `for` loop at some point, the reason that loops in high-level language (i.e. not compiled) such as python take so much computational recourses is because the interpreter decides on the data type on-the-fly (which results in flexibility, unlike low level languages such as `c`). Because in  numpy you set the data type (at least you should if you deal with just numerical data), it gives you performance comparable to compiled languages such as `c`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and the references. I just had to mention that and would be great to see a time comparison if possible.

Comment: After a substantial check - you were absolutely right regarding the `np.apply_along_axis`. In this case it does perform worse that the regular `for` loop. I think that the reason for it is the relativly small number of operations performed in each iteration, so the header of the function acts as a bottlenec. I've corrected my answer.  Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: That is a good comparison, informative! Thanks for taking time to go through in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when using your exact data, but using an 3x4x5 example similar to yours, this code:

```
## make a 2d array of ones.
x = np.ones().reshape(3,1)

## mutiply those by an array of  [1,2,...,20]
## 20 because we want 4x5 max value
x = x*np.arange(1, 4*5+1)

## test where those are greater than the row number
## change the '3+1' expression to change the value of the comparison.
x = (x <= np.arange(1, 3+1).reshape(3, 1))

## booleans -> ints, reshape 2d to 3d (3x4x5) array
x = x.astype(int).reshape(-1, 4, 5)
```

produces this output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

It's going to be a lot faster than iteration, so I hope it helps.

To make the code a little more generic,

```
## assign values for the axis lengths
ax_0_len = 3
ax_1_len = 4
ax_2_len = 5

## then replace the 3, 4, and 5 above with these variables.
```